# std::function needs address to function on vs2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I found this strange behavior when working with std::function.
The code below compiles with no warnings on VS2012, but when executed there is a memory access violation in the type_traits function `forward`.

```cpp
typedef std::function<void()> Func;

void defaultFunc() { /* no-op */ }

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
  Func f = argc == 0 ? Func() : defaultFunc; // crash
  return 0;
}
```

I double checked on gnu g++ 4.9.2 which didn't reproduce the problem.

If I add an ampersand to the defaultFunc everything works:

```
Func f = argc == 0 ? Func() : &defaultFunc; // works
```

If I remove the ternary conditional it works as expected.

```
Func f = defaultFunc; // works
```

What is happening here?

Comment: Why on earth don't you start out by testing with *modern* compilers?

Comment: The "C++11" in VS 2012 is far from it.

Comment: Most likely, bug in VS with different types for ternary operator. I had a similar one long long time ago in SunCC.